# Bulk File Renaming - Extract parent foldername and use in file renaming

Tags: powershell

PowerShell novice here again with my proof of concept.

The code below successfully extracts attached files from .msg files located in folders and leaves the extracted filename without changing it. What I'm now looking for now is to extract part of the parent folder name, with standard format of...

nnnn+string (e.g. "8322 MyStudy") i.e. 4 digits followed by a space then string.

...to rename the extracted filename from...

ExtractedFilename.pdf to "0nnnn - ExtractedFilename.pdf". e.g. "08322 - ExtractedFilename.pdf"

My main problem is how to extract the numeric part of the parent folder name (from where my module will be run). I'm hoping that my poor PS formatting skills will allow me to do the rest.

Once again, any help appreciated.

```
##
## Source: https://chris.dziemborowicz.com/blog/2013/05/18/how-to-batch-extract-attachments-from-msg-files-using-powershell/
##
## Usage: Expand-MsgAttachment *
##
##

function Expand-MsgAttachment
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Path", Position=0, Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$Path,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="LiteralPath", Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName="FileInfo", Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$Item
    )

    Begin
    {
        # Load application
        Write-Verbose "Loading Microsoft Outlook..."
        $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    }

    Process
    {
        switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
        {
            "Path"        { $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path }
            "LiteralPath" { $files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $LiteralPath }
            "FileInfo"    { $files = $Item }
        }

        $files | % {
            # Work out file names
            $msgFn = $_.FullName
            # extract path, e.g. 'c:\path\to\'
            $msgPath = Split-Path -Path $msgFn


            # Skip non-.msg files
            if ($msgFn -notlike "*.msg") {
                Write-Verbose "Skipping $_ (not an .msg file)..."
                return
            }

            # Extract message body
            Write-Verbose "Extracting attachments from $_..."
            $msg = $outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate($msgFn)
            $msg.Attachments | % {
                # Work out attachment file name
                #$attFn = $msgFn -replace '\.msg$', " - Attachment - $($_.FileName)"
                $attFn = Join-Path -Path $msgPath -ChildPath ($_.FileName)

                # Do not try to overwrite existing files
                if (Test-Path -literalPath $attFn) {
                    Write-Verbose "Skipping $($_.FileName) (file already exists)..."
                    return
                }

                # Save attachment
                Write-Verbose "Saving $($_.FileName)..."
                $_.SaveAsFile($attFn)

                # Output to pipeline
                Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $attFn
            }
        }
    }

    # This function to rename expanded attachment file to study renaming standards
    Function RenameExpandedAttachments {
    }

    End
    {
        Write-Verbose "Done."
    }
}
```

Comment: There was no need to post your whole here irrelevant script. Getting experience in coding often means trial and error, if you reassure every single step you won't get far.

Answer (score 0):

The currently running script is :

```
$script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Use `Split-Path` to get only the Path,

```
Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

to get only the last element use again Split-Path with the -Leaf parameter

```
Split-Path -Leaf (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
```

To extract leading numbers use a Regular Expression with a (capture group).

```
'^(\d+) (.*)$'
```

And wrap all this in an if:

```
If ((Split-Path -Leaf (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)) -match '^(\d+) (.*)$'){
    $NewName = "{0:00000} - {1}" -f $Matches[1],$ExtractedFileName
} else {
    "No numbers found in this path"
}
```

Comment: Not a fan of the .Net regex? `[regex]::Matches($($File.Directory.Name), '^(\d*+)')`

Comment: Tried using part of your answer by adding this line ($myinvocationfolder = Split-Path -Leaf (Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)) within my module. My debugger implied that the 'Path' value was the location of my module in \My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\modulename. I'm really looking for the name of the foldername where the user will be importing and executing this module from. I also noticed that my variable $myinvocationfolder was empty. Does this clarify my requirement? Thanks

Comment: @RobCodyStuff You will need to use the `$File.Directory.Name` as the string for your `regex`. This is where your .msg files are coming from so it will get the name of the folder that they are in. EG. `C:\Temp\8322 MyStudy\Testfile.msg`. `$File.Directory.Name` will output `8322 MyStudy`.

Comment: @RobCodyStuff maybe I understood `My main problem is how to extract the numeric part of the parent folder name (from where my module will be run)` wrong or it was worded unlucky.

Comment: @LotPings I assume he meant the location specified for the function within the module. I could be wrong but I couldn't see a practical use for using the parent folder for your module repository. Classic stichup.

Comment: Hi Drew, I'm having trouble (absolute novice user of PS) using this. I added this ($MyFoldername = $File.Directory.Name) to my code and my debug sessions indicates blank values when hovering over parameters. What context should I be using your suggestion?

Comment: Hi LotPings, I'll be executing the module from a folder like "...\8322 MyStudy\" from within PS command line window. As this is the only folder within the hierarchy with that format then I need to extract the study number and apply it to rename the files I find in it's sub-folders. Sorry for the confusion but still learning about the right terms to use to describe my problem. Does this help?

Comment: To get the current directory name use `Split-Path -Leaf (pwd)` or `(Get-Item (pwd)).Name`

Comment: Hi LotPings, I added a line using both your suggestions (e.g. $myfolder = Split-Path -Leaf (pwd)) to my debug session but still null/empty values resulting. Any suggestions?

Comment: @LotPings - It is better not to use aliases in written scripts. `Split-Path -Leaf (Get-Location) or (Get-Item (Get-Location)).Name`

Comment: @lit, sorry but no. While trying to pinpoint a problem I'll use aliases; different thing when posting a flu fledged answer.